There exist an explicit function with these properties?
There exist a smooth function satisfying $f(t)\leq 1/|t|^{p}$ where $0<p<4/(N-2)$, with $N \geq 3$ natural when $1<|t|<2$ and $f(t)=1$ when $|t| \leq 1$ and $f(t)=0$ when $|t|\geq 2$ ?
I'm searching a function like this to do an application in partial differential equations, the usual bump function does not work well, so I'm searching new alternatives on how to construct explicitely a function with these properties.

There is no such function. More specifically, there is no function $f(t)$ such that:

$f(t)=1$ for $t\le 1$;
$f$ is continuously differentiable on a neighborhood of $t=1$;
$f(t) \le 1/t^p$ where $p$ is a positive constant.

Let $f(t)$ satisfy the first two conditions, and let $g(t) = f(t) - 1/t^p$. Then $g'(t) = f'(t) + p/{t^{p+1}}$, and in particular $g'(1)=p>0$ (since $f'(1)$ must equal its one-sided derivative from the left, which is $0$). It follows that $g'(t)$ is positive in some neighborhood of $t=1$, and so $g(t)$ is increasing on that neighborhood; but $g(1)=0$, so $g(t)>0$ just to the right of $t=1$, which means that $f(t) > 1/t^p$ there.

thank you! just one more question: now that I know that is not possible to construct a differentiable function with these properties, if I ask that the function is only continuous, so in this case the construction is possible, right?

Hint: piecewise linear functions are continuous.
